# Sorting by price or rate

Tags: php, sql, mysql-num-rows

So this is my code, but whenever I run this code i get this message 
(Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in F:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 31) and I can't find the problem.
I always use num_rows and it works, this is the first time this happened

```
 <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost','root','','instruments');
if(isset($_GET['order']))
{
$order = $_GET ['order'];
}else{
  $order = 'price';
}
if(isset($_GET['sort']))
{
$sort = $_GET ['sort'];
}else{
  $sort = 'ASC';
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM bass ORDER BY $order $sort");
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
echo "
<table border = '1'>
<tr>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Rate</th>
";
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
{

      $name = $rows ['name'];
  $price = $rows ['price'];
  $rate = $rows ['rate'];
  $image = $rows ['image'];

  echo "
  <tr>
  <td>$name</td>
 <td>$price</td>
 <td>$rate</td>
 <td><img src='$image'></td>
   </tr>
  ";
}
echo "
</table>
";
}else {
  echo "Nic ni";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: your query is failing, so `$result` is false/NULL

Comment: check for mysqli::error to know why it's failing.

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: add this after `$result = $mysqli->query(...`: `echo $mysqli->error;`. This will tell you what is wrong. maybe a table name, maybe a field name, ..

Comment: I did it like this and got the same result         $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM bass ORDER BY $order $sort ") echo $mysqli->error;

Comment: _but what does the error message say_?! (in your example is the `;` missing after `..$order $sort);`

Comment: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object , it only says that and nothing else

Comment: Ok I finally did it, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Run this query in your MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM bass ORDER BY price ASC
```

Check if you get any result. Maybe your query is returning 0 results and that's why it's failing.